# complex markup with media queries or server side detection of device for responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design

We are working on a responsive website. We have been developing mockups for certain pages that make the reuse of the exact same markup for desktop and mobile version impossible.

The question (from a software engineer's point of view) is this:

Is it better to (A) create double versions for the markup of the same parts (i.e. a contact form) for desktop and mobile versions and employ media queries to show/hide on occasion the markup?

Or is it better to (B) use server side detection of device/screen resolution and parse into the browser the appropriate version of the markup?

With (A) we have eventually more complicated markup returned to the browser with, on occasion, big parts of it hidden (display:none) and duplicate markup for some parts of the page. Not good for mobile devices that need as simple and concise a markup as possible. Nevertheless, option (A) sounds like the more theoretically correct approach to responsive design.

With (B) we have much simpler and cleaner markup returned to the browser since on the side of the server we make the decision of which parts of the markup to return. On the other hand we lose the flexibility of the page being fully responsive when, for instance, a desktop browser window is resized (since the markup will come from the server and not being able to change on window resize).

There is no option to redesign the page as to use the same elements with different positioning/sizes.

There is no option to use a mobile version (different domain) of the site.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for server-side detection ;)

Comment: we eventually are going with the server-side approach. Less unneeded markup in the browser. Although it does feel more like a discrete mobile version is developed and not a responsive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the server side detection because you don't want the mobile clients loading large amounts of unnecessary markup. Also, the idea behind responsive design is that it reuses the same code across devices, however it sounds like you are working with two different designs that will prevent you from taking an approach that would involve media queries.

Best of luck!

Comment: I agree 100%. As the architect of large scale web apps for financial companies, it all starts to add up. The DOM is still traversed if display is non and if you have any form of MVC data-binding (Angular, Backbone, etc), it can add significant overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I, respectfully, disagree with Alec. display:none ads very little weight if none to the loading time of the markup. If engineered correctly you will not have any problems. At our company, we put out anywhere between 30 to 40 applications, all responsive and all mobile-friendly. We use approach A.

Although it is a good idea to sympathize with older versions of mobile browsing capabilities, you must consider which one will outlast the other. Phones are updated quite frequently, while the website will remain 3 to 4 times longer.

Code for the future. We, engineers, are responsible for creating the technology the future will implement.

My two cents